# Android widget using a config activity wont update

Tags: android, widget, android-appwidget

I am making an Android widget to display real time transportation information based on bus stop numbers.  It displays the next 3 bus arrivals for the stop number and has a button where the user can refresh the data.  That was working ok until I tried adding my widget configuration activity.

Now when you select the widget, a configuration screen is opened where you enter your bus stop number.  Once you do that the widget is added to the home screen, but it will not execute the method to gather data and the refresh button will not work for that either.  I have not been able to figure out why.

WidgetConfig

```
public class WidgetConfig extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText info;
AppWidgetManager awm;
Context c;
int awID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.widget_config);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bWidgetConfig);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    c = WidgetConfig.this;

    //getting info about the widget that launched this activity
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
    if (extras != null){
        awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }else{
        finish();
    }
    awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(c);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    info = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etWidgetConfig);
    String e = info.getText().toString();

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvStopNum, e);

    Intent in = new Intent(c, WidgetConfig.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(c, 0, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.tvStopNum, pi);  

    awm.updateAppWidget(awID, views);

    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();       
}
```

AppWidgetProvider

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    // Create a new intent that will target this class
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[0]);
    intent.setAction("update");

    // Create a new PendingIntent which will be run whenever the refresh button is pressed
    // This PendingIntent will run the intent we just created before this
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pi);

    // Manually run the AsyncTask to initially populate the 5 question fields
    new RTPIinformation().execute(context);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);    
}

// This method is called when it receives an Intent.  In particular, it will
// receive an intent whenever the refresh button is clicked
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equals("update")){
        new RTPIinformation().execute(context);
    }

}

class RTPIinformation extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, List<RealtimeData>>{
     .
     .
     .
      }
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ruben.dublin.bus.widget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".WidgetConfig"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver 
        android:name=".MyWidgetProvider" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated